# Good way to sanitize input in classic asp

Tags: security, asp-classic, sanitization

I have to update old projects at work. I do not have any experience with classic asp, although i'm familiar with php scripting.

- Are there any functions I should use?
- Can you provide me with a good function for some basic protection?
- Is there something like a parameterized query in asp?

Thanks!

Comment: "Sanitize" is the wrong way to think about the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can use parametrized queries in classic ASP (more accurately, classic ADO).

Here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150207201957/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190).

As for encoding output, I might be tempted to create a wrapper for the latest Microsoft Anti-XSS library and call it with Server.CreateObject.  I am far from an expert on this kind of thing as I spend much more time in .Net, so I only think this would work.

Server.HTMLEncode is really not good enough, as it only blacklists a few encoding characters.  The Anti-XSS library is much better as it whitelists what is acceptable.

Comment: +1 for wrapping Microsoft Anti-XSS library. After much trial & error this is what we ended up doing.

Comment: In other words: you **don't** sanitize it. You _quarantine_ it to it's own place where there's no danger it can be treated as code.

Comment: Be careful using CreateObject to invoke COM resources on server applications. When other users activate the same, it instantiates multiple processes and can cause resource and rights issues that can lead to 500 errors.

Answer (score 7):

Always use Server.HTMLEncode to sanitize user input.

For example, if you're setting a variable from a form text box:

firstName = Server.HTMLEncode(trim(request.form("firstname")))

Comment: Actually you should never sanitize input using HTMLEncode. This is only useful for sanitizing _output_. There is no guarantee the input is to be displayed by a web browser. The only thing that you need to protect from is SQL injection (so, e.g. the single quote char and the semicolon). Even better is to require e.g. an int using CLNG in a query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for SQL injection. Do not concatenate user input to a SQL string and then execute it. Instead, always used parameterized queries.

Comment: Yes idd, can i use parameterized queries in classic asp?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of functions starting with Is, such as `IsNumber`, `IsArray` etcetera, that might be of interest. Also if you're expecting a integer, you could use `CLng(Request("blabla"))` to get it, thus if it's not a integer the CLng function will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it might be to add a check in a `header.asp` file that iterates through the `Request` object looking for inappropriate characters.  For example:

```
<%
    for each x in Request.Form ' Do this for Request.Querystring also
        If InStr(x,"<") <> 0 Then
            ' encode the value or redirect to error page?
        End If
    next
%>
```

Comment: The Request object is read-only so you couldn't directly edit the values, but I have for some projects created a Dictionary object into which I've dumped all the values from the incoming form, and those values can be manipulated any way you like...