# Using Javascript for redirecting is true or not?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, xss

I have a base page in asp.net.
In this page if there is a problem authentication, it automatically redirects to login page with this code:

```
response.write("<script>window.open('" & LoginPage & "','_parent');</script>");
```

Does this have a security problem?
I mean using javascript for redirecting to another page has a security problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, anything that hasn't been sanitized from user input poses a threat. if LoginPage variable comes from user input, then it can indeed be a security problem, if not handled correctly... otherwise no.

This question has some useful replies [Good way to sanitize input in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444181/good-way-to-sanitize-input-in-classic-asp)

In addition.. JavaScript is client-side, meaning it has no effect on your server, only the client.